# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tid')

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting, csrf

Recently I noticed our salesforce instance spitting the following into the console on user login

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tid')
```

No changes have been made in production and our sandbox running the same code still works and allows login perfectly fine, the console also spits out multiple of these errors

```
Visualforce Remoting Exception: Remoting request invalid for your session. Refresh the page and try again
```

This has only happened over the last couple of weeks so curious if anyone else is having similar issues?

Comment: If anyone happens to run into this issue, was resolved by disabling caching on the page